# vb.net Breadcrumb navigation limit

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, breadcrumbs

Im currently trying to set up breadcrumbs on my site, Ive tried two different approaches and the max I have seem to get is only 3 levels on the breadcrumbs. Is there a limit to it?

```
Home> Hello World > Good Bye

Home> Hello World > Good Bye > Forever
```

E.g. I never seem to be able to get Forever to show on the breadcrumb. Is there a limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using asp.net SiteMapPath correct? Make sure you **have not** set the [ParentLevelsDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.parentlevelsdisplayed.aspx) of SiteMapPath.
Or is it generated dynamically using some other means?

**Edit:**
The last one Forever is a directory right? Take this sample sitemap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Home"  description="">
            <siteMapNode url="" title="1"  description="">
                <siteMapNode url="" title="2"  description="">
                     <siteMapNode url="~/test/1/2/3/Default.aspx" title="3"  description="" />
                </siteMapNode>
            </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

It gives this output:

[image: Sitemappath e.g.]

So you see Default.aspx is in folder 3 and it is displaying fine.
May be you might want to share your sitemappath and folder structure.

Comment: Yes I am using SiteMapPath. the hierarchy of the breadcrumb is in the web.sitemap. I don't think I am using ParentLevelsDisplay